# Accessing second monitor in WPF when monitor setup set for "Show Desktop Only On 1"

Tags: wpf, windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm writing an application that will be run on a windows 7 system with a monitor and a front panel as a dual screen setup.  Virtual desktop software will be used to access it most of the time, and the virtualization software should ONLY show what is on the monitor, not the front panel.

When set for "Extend these displays", the virtualization software shows both screens spliced together, and there does not appear to be a way to turn it off.  If I set the Multiple Displays setting to be "Show Desktop Only On 1", the virtualization system works correctly, but now in my WPF application it's as if the second monitor does not exist.  My Screen.AllScreens array only shows one monitor.

Is there a way I can get my WPF application to show on the second monitor in full screen mode when the desktop is set for "Show Desktop Only On 1"?  For purposes of this application, it will ONLY ever be full screen.

Comment: interesting question. if you don't get an answer and end up hacking WinAPI, please post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong angle. You need to look at the virtual desktop software and not your app or Windows itself.

First off, for Windows to use dual screens, which you want, you must set "Extend these displays". Without this, it is impossible for Windows or any other software to use the second display.

Secondly, under "virtual desktop software" I assume something like Remote Desktop, TeamViewer or VNC. All of those programs should allow you to select whether to show all displays. For instance in Remote Desktop, before connecting you can select Options -> Display -> uncheck "Use all of my monitors for remote sessions".

If on the other hand you are looking for a way to **limit** the end user, that he/she couldn't in no way access or see the other monitor, then you must find a virtual desktop software that can only show the main display (this might be very hard, because most software can handle multi-display setups). The other solution is to extend your own software to stream it's main screen output to another machine and accept input from it - think of writing your own virtual desktop software.